# Passing data from UISplitView to UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

It seems actually to be a simple task. But somehow it crashes all the time. And I do not understand why.

I made a custom class for my UITableViewController (MasterViewController) and I have 2 custom classes for my UISplitViewController.

I have got a variable in my MasterViewController which I want to get set by the UISplitView which controls it.

I call this in my viewDidLoad() function from the UISplitViewController class:

```
 let masterVC  = self.splitViewController?.viewControllers.first as! MasterViewController
    masterVC.variable = 1
```

the error says: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode= 0x0)

What is happening there? is the instance of the view controller not loaded jet?
How can I simply just set the variable?

Comment: Without you sharing more of your code, it's difficult to assess what exactly is going on here. Apparently, masterVC is nil which causes the error but I'm not sure whether the viewControllers array is empty or the forced cast to MasterViewController fails...

Comment: I don't know what more I can show. I just saw in debug mode : self.splitViewController?.viewControllers = nil

Comment: Btw, why are you accessing splitViewController? in the UISplitViewController class? Is it placed in another UISplitViewController? Have you tried using self.viewControllers.first?